# Airflow job fails with empty hostname

Tags: airflow, airflow-celery

I am using `airflow:2.3.3` with celery. Recently I notice alot of random job failures and the hostname appear missing, so it seem like the scheduler didnt even schedule the task correctly

[image]

I tried updating the airflow.cfg for scheduler/webserver

```
hostname_callable = airflow.utils.net.get_host_ip_address
```

But it doesnt help

In the logs, I see

```
*** Fetching from: http://:8793/log/dag_id=xxx/run_id=xxx/task_id=xxx/attempt=1.log
                        ^ notice host is empty
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be a configuration issue with the hostname or IP address that the Airflow scheduler is using to communicate with the Celery workers. Here are a few things you can try to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Double-check the `hostname_callable` configuration in your `airflow.cfg` file. Make sure it is set to a valid function that returns the hostname or IP address of the Airflow scheduler machine. The `get_host_ip_address` function you mentioned should work fine, but you can also try using `socket.gethostname` or `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`.
2. Check the logs for the Celery workers to see if there are any error messages related to hostname resolution or communication. Look for lines that contain "celery.worker" or "celery.task". If there are any errors related to hostnames or IP addresses, it might give you a clue as to what the issue is.
3. Verify that the Celery workers are running on the same network as the Airflow scheduler, and that they can communicate with each other. Check that there are no firewall rules or network restrictions that might be blocking communication between the machines.
4. If none of the above steps help, you can try setting the `worker_hijack_root_logger` configuration in `airflow.cfg` to `False`. This will prevent the Celery workers from hijacking the root logger and printing their own log messages. Sometimes this can cause issues with hostname resolution or logging, so turning it off might help.

Hopefully one of these steps will help you identify and resolve the issue with the missing hostname.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! We realised its due to an outdated deployment on some workers causing this weird issue ... unsure why code changes will affect such a thing. Thought it will be shown in the execution logs instead.